# How can I unset this command "npm config set cache "C:/Users/ASIMIM/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache" --global"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, command-line

npx create-react-app my-app wasn't working for me it was showing this

[image]

then i went on stackoverflow did the same thing that was shown that was "npm config set cache "C:/Users/ASIMIM/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache" --global"   and now it is showing this
[image]

help me to unset this command "npm config set cache "C:/Users/ASIMIM/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache" --global"

Comment: Please use `npx create-react-app my-app` instead, where `my-app` is a folder that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you previously had it set to the default value, you can delete  the key.

To delete the `cache` key from all config files:

```
npm config delete cache
```

If you want to be extra careful, you can edit just the global config file:

```
npm config edit --global
```

If you choose the edit route, you will need to find the right entry in the file for `cache` and comment it out or delete it.

(If you had previously set the value to something other than the default and want to restore *that* value, re-run your `npm config cache set` command with the value you had before.)